# Render компонента из уже существующей html строки

Tags: reactjs, render

Доброго времени суток!

Я хочу реализовать создание компонента из уже подготовленной строки html и объекта стиля с помощью React. Имеются следующие данные:

```
const obj = {
    block1: '<div>TEST-1</div>',
    block2: '<div>TEST-2</div>',
};
const styling = {
    block1: { fontSize: '12px', color: '#123456' },
    block2: { fontSize: '18px', color: '#153426' },
};
```

В результате я хотел бы создать 2 блока:

```
<div style="font-size:12px; color:#123456;">TEST-1</div>
<div style="font-size:18px; color:#153426;">TEST-2</div>
```

Я уже пробовал 2 модуля npm для реализации этой идеи (без стилизации):

- ReactHtmlParser - создает компонент из любой строки html
- JsxParser - может одновременно отображать компоненты + jsx

Но я получаю ту же ошибку за все время: *Component.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.*

Мой render выглядит так:

```
render() {
    const customBlock = getBlock(obj, styling); // объекты объявлены выше
    return(
        <Component1 />
        { customBlock }
        <Component2 />
    );
}
```

Может быть, кто-то может помочь понять, почему компонент из функции getBlock возвращает то, что не может быть отображено?

```
getBlock = (block, styling) => {
    let markup = '';
    for (let element in block) {
        if (block[element]) {
            markup += block[element];
        }
    }
    return <JsxParser bindings={{}} components={{}} jsx={`${markup}`} />
    // ИЛИ
    // return ReactHtmlParser(markup);
}
```

P.S. другие компоненты - это обычные объекты {props...}, динамические компоненты имеют такую же структуру, но дополнительно оборачиваются объектом «body» {body: {props...}}. Поэтому ReactElement.isValidElement не может проверить свойство $$type объекта из-за этой обёртки 'body' =(

Comment: Учитывая цикл, у вас на выходе получается несколько элементов, попробуйте обернуть вызов - `return <div>{ ReactHtmlParser(markup) }</div>;`

Comment: Начните с того, что посмотрите что у вас вообще возвращается, сразу станет понятно что не так.